# Continuity of $x^2$ at $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In proving that $x^2$ is continuous at $x=1$ (or any non-zero real number), is the following sufficient as a proof?

$f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$ if $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 : |x-1|<\delta \implies |x^2-1| < \varepsilon$.

Pick $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon + 1}-1$.

Then if $|x-1| < \delta$,  $|x^2-1| = |x-1||x+1| = |x-1||(x-1)+2| <|x-1|(|x-1|+2) < \delta(\delta+2) = \varepsilon$

If this is correct, why do you most commonly see proofs of this involving taking $\delta$ to be the minimum of 1 and something else? Is that considered simpler?

Comment: Seems sufficient to me. Most of us are not as clever as you are.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean it like that! It just seems to me like it would be simpler not splitting delta in to two different cases. But I appreciate the actually calculation is more complicated this way.

Comment: to me, the simplest way in that particular case would be proving that $x^2$ is differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: That last $<$ should be an $=$, right? I might also add in an extra step there explicitly showing that $\delta(\delta + 2) = \varepsilon$, personally.

Comment: Your method is good indeed. And the deleted post just confirmed what I said :b

Answer (score 4):

One common misconception in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs for beginners is that they try to find $\delta$ by *solving* inequalities of the form $g(\delta;x,y,\cdots)<\epsilon$ directly.

This works for some simple cases but it usually makes things unnecessarily complicated and sometimes undoable. (Imagine how you would give an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for continuity of $f(x)=x^3+x^2+3x+5$ at $x=1$. `(:`)

For your particular case, just look at the goal: $|x^2-1|<\epsilon$. This is equivalent to
$$
|x-1||x+1|<\epsilon\tag{1}
$$

The estimate (1) tells you that if $x$ is close to $1$, then you can make the whole quantity on the left small since $|x-1|$ would be small and $|x+1|$ is bounded.

Say you first restrict that $\delta\le1$, then if $|x-1|<\delta$, you have $$|x+1|<|x-1+2|\le |x-1|+2<3.$$

Now if you make further $\delta$ smaller so that
$$
\delta\cdot 3\le\epsilon\tag{2}
$$
you get the desired estimate in (1).

To wrap things up, you can set $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/3)$.